# What is the difference in representing colours this way #ffffff and 0xffffff?

Tags: colors, binary, hex, rgb

Sorry if its a newbie question but entering new territory and google hasn't been very helpful and would love a fresh description
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way we represent colors is dependent on the system we try to use this color value. I do not know what language you're refering to in your question, but you can find `#ffffff` used in [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), while integer form `0xffffff` can be seen in different programming languages.

*You may wonder why it is in HEX?*

Just because it's easier to see the value of the color, as it's being presented in a way of 255 bytes for each color respectively. So, you can see that `0xff0000` is a pure red. Compare it to value of `16711680` - this is the same value but it does not tell you what color it is.

Every web/css developer can spot the pattern here*:

```
#ffffff, #cccccc, #aaaaaa, #999999, #666666, #333333, #000000
```

As it's just set colors from White to Black and some shades of gray in between.

Hope this helps!

---

*for CSS in particular, the above pattern should be written as:

```
#fff, #ccc, #aaa, #999, #666, #333, #000
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, but do you happen to know what the x in 0xffffff represents?

Comment: 0x - is just a prefix that hints the compiler to treat following symbols as a sequence of HEX characters.

Comment: Thank you so much! I want to like your answer but website doesnt let me because i dont have 15 reputation points yet

Comment: No problem, like when you can :)